# How to Place Search Icon inside Text Input Field using W3.CSS

Tags: html, css, w3.css

I am creating a search box for a sidebar. I need to place search icon inside the text feild and can't seem to get the result.

`<input class="w3-input" type="text" placeholder="Search..."> <i class="w3-input-icon fa fa-search"></i>`

It's giving output like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dJby.png)

How to align it at the right side.

Comment: You can't. `input` elements do not have content.

Comment: You *could* overlay it using positioning or a transform but without a [mcve] it's hard to assist further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't place an HTML element inside an input, but you can overlay it (place it on top). Below, the search icon is placed over the input field by absolutely positioning it within a relatively positioned container, ensuring it appears on top of the input and to the right side. I've added `pointer-events:none;` so when the user clicks the icon, it does not block interaction with the input.

```css
.search-box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.w3-input {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.search-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 12px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/w3-css/4.1.0/w3.min.css" integrity="sha512-Z6UIAdEZ7JNzeX5M/c5QZj+oqbldGD+E8xJEoOwAx5e0phH7kdjsWULGeK5l2UjehKtChHDaUY2rQAF/NEiI9w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
<div class="search-box">
  <input class="w3-input" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
  <i class="fa fa-search search-icon"></i>
</div>
```